# How to grab all files of FTP server and display in GRIDVIEW?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to extract filename,filesize,Date from WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails ???

Note :- I done with ListView ..
my coding

```
private void btnListFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  string[] filenames = GetFilesDetailList();
 dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
  foreach (string filename in filenames)
 {
 dataGridView1.Rows.Add(filename)
 }
}

    private string[] GetFilesDetailList()
    {

            ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
            ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
            WebResponse response = ftp.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                result.Append(line);
                result.Append("\n");
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }

            result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf("\n"), 1);
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
            return result.ToString().Split('\n');
            //MessageBox.Show(result.ToString().Split('\n'));
        }
```

Comment: What about this is giving you the problem? As you've written the question, it sounds like you want somebody to do this for you.

Comment: @user1666620   hi, i edited the question please see ..  it populate entirely in one column. but i want to populate under each column respectively

Comment: can you show your code please?

Comment: please see above @user1666620

Comment: What are the values in the `ListDirectoryDetails` delimited by?  Seems trivial to find that out and then split accordingly and then assign individually to columns in a `DataTable` and then assign that `DataTable` as your `DataSource`.

Comment: ok, so what you really want is to add columns to your datagrid and populate them?

Comment: yes Mr/Mrs. @user1666620